# Debug authorisation in R curl using NTLM

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to access a URL from a windows (sharepoint 2007) web server within a corporate network.  I'm using R and curl but can't seem to get the authorization part right. (There is no proxy or firewall between me and the web server, and I'm on a windows machine on the same domain)  This is what I've currently got;

```
library(SSOAP)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

#This works fine for a page with no authroisation required
y = tryCatch(getURLContent("http://www.example.com/webpagewithnoauthroisation.html", 
                verbose=TRUE, 
                httpauth="ntlm", userpwd="DOMAIN/username:password"), 
        HTTPError = function(e) {
            cat("HTTP error: ", e$message, "\n")
        })

#This fails for a page that needs authoisation
x = tryCatch(getURLContent("http://sharepoint.example.com/Pages/Default.aspx", 
                verbose=TRUE, 
                httpauth="ntlm", userpwd="DOMAIN/username:password"), 
        HTTPError = function(e) {
            cat("HTTP error: ", e$message, "\n")
        })

> Error: Unauthorized
```

I'm a bit stumped how to debug this (on my Windows machine).  Any good suggestions on debugging (r) Curl authentication issues ?

Edit: I thought it would be NTLM, but have just read that it may something else (Kerberos ?).  The target web server is a Sharepoint 2007 server.